# Remote Event Receivers without Azure Access Control Service (ACS)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, acs, sharepoint-addin

I have a requirement where I need to create Remote Event Receivers for SharePoint Online list because Event Receivers were used in SharePoint 2010 version.

According to various sources and examples, it seems that Provider Hosted Add-In is the way to create Remote Event Receivers which requires Azure Access Control Service (ACS).

As Azure Access Control Service (ACS) is about to be [deprecated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/time-to-migrate-off-access-control-service/), is there any other way to create Remote Event Receivers for SharePoint Online list?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SharePoint Online Remote Event Receiver still necessary to use Azure Access Control Service and it is still available now until Nov 7 2018.

In the future, after ACS deprecated, I think Microsoft will have alternative way to handle Remote Event Receiver for SharePoint Online, but now please still use ACS.